# Using JTransforms on Android to calculated FFT of amplitude data in double array

Tags: android, fft

I'm trying to use JTransforms (https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms) to calculate the FFT of some amplitude data saved in a double array in Android. I'm pretty new to both Android's programming and Jtransforms/FFT so I want to ask a few questions:

1. In all the example I found here in stackoverflow about jtransform I saw people import the library in the code by
   `import edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.;`
   but for me that dont really work. If I do that Eclipse say "The import edu cannot be resolved", what did I do wrong here? I've already import the JTransforms-3.0.jar in the project by Build Path>Config Build Path>Libraries>Add External JARs and then >Order and Export tab>tick the JTransforms-3.0.jar and then OK.
   Also if I do `import org.jtransforms.fft.;` then it work but is it the same as the 
   `import edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.*;`   ?
2. When I study about the FFT they say 1 thing different from FFT compare to DFT is that the number of data to be input in FFT must be a power of 2 right? Do the same applied to Jtransform's FFT? And this example (https://gist.github.com/jongukim/4037243) is how to do FFT with JTransform right?